# Need to handle the rows that don't get picked

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the following, we are picking all patients who saw a Dr. but we remove 4 Doctors from this, because they are no longer in our facility. The problem here is that if a patient has ONLY seen from these 4 Doctors, they will not get selected. In fact, we want to assign them to `b.Appt_resource_id = 142`. How would i be able to also include such patients? The data we are getting from this sql looks like this:

```
    110811      737470                  Mirta  AVostaquishpe        19  

    102028      664770                  Brune  Alexgdre     19  

    70038       361830                  Pala  Avtila        19  

    44684       112740                  Nani  Verez     19  

    71939       382620                  Alex  Voachim       19
```

You can see that each patient is assigned to a Doctor via this b.Appt_Resource_ID. but this leaves out patients who have ONLY seen from the 4 Doctors who left the facility by now. How to included them and assign them to b.appt_resource_id= 142.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.Patient_id,
    P.Patient_name,
    P.Patient_Last_Name,
    A.Patient_number,
    b.Appt_resource_id,
    b.appt_resource_descr 
FROM
    [PM].[vwGenPatApptInfo] A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        patient_id,
        Appt_resource_id,
        appt_resource_descr, 
        COUNT(Appt_resource_id) AS DR_count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS seqnum
    FROM
        [PM].[vwGenPatApptInfo]
    WHERE
        Patient_ID IS NOT NULL AND
        Appt_Sched_Department_ID = 2 AND
        Appt_resource_id not IN (115, 123, 94, 109)
    GROUP BY
        patient_id,
        Appt_resource_id,
        appt_resource_descr
    ORDER BY
        patient_id,
        seqnum 
    ) B
    ON B.Patient_ID = A.Patient_ID  
    AND B.seqnum = 1 
INNER JOIN
    [PM].[vwGenPatInfo] P 
    ON A.Patient_id = P.Patient_id
WHERE
    A.Appt_Cancelled_Date IS NULL AND
    A.Appt_Noshow_date IS NULL
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data, explain how data is coming up now and the desired behavior

Answer (score 0):

Take out the line where you filter out the four doctors, and use this line in your main SELECT instead:

```
CASE 
   WHEN b.Appt_resource_id IN (115, 123, 94, 109) THEN 142 
   ELSE b.Appt_resource_id 
END AS Appt_resource_id
```

Comment: oh i see let me try that

Comment: See the issue is, it is possible that you saw one of the 4 Doctors but also one of the non 4. So in that case, you would belong to the other Dr. not to Dr 142.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are over complicating your query a lot.  You actually do not want to limit your result set of your Appointments you just want to change the resource ID when it falls within certain values, thought I would question that too because you probably would like to know how many different doctors they saw.  To do that you can use a case statement.

Here is a query to get the list of patients meeting the criteria counting the doctors (with the 4 changed to 1) and appointments.  To get all of the appointment details would be a different type of query but doable so if that is what you want let us know.

```
SELECT
    p.Patient_id
    ,P.Patient_name
    ,P.Patient_Last_Name
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN a.Appt_resource_id IN (115, 123, 94, 109) THEN 142 ELSE a.Appt_resource_id END) as DistinctDrCount
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT a.Appt_resource_id) as ActualUnAlteredDrCount
    ,COUNT(*) as NumOfAppointments
FROM
    [vwGenPatApptInfo] a
    INNER JOIN [PM].[vwGenPatInfo] P 
    ON A.Patient_id = P.Patient_id
WHERE
    A.Appt_Cancelled_Date IS NULL AND
    A.Appt_Noshow_date IS NULL
GROUP BY
    p.Patient_id
    ,P.Patient_name
    ,P.Patient_Last_Name
```